# Wordpress Bootstrap dropdown not working after moving to another server

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've got [webpage](http://sachy.orkistan.cz/) based on wordpress (uses bootstrap3 template) which I recently moved on another server. Since then dropdown menu is not working. It may be that I've forgotten some css or js files, but console is not saying anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The console says there's an error in your main.js at line 3, try to fix it as it might be breaking other Javascripts in your page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `box-slider-fade.jquery.min.js` script cannot be found (404 error).
Check if this file is present in your theme `library/js/effects/` directory.

Comment: I removed it during fixing errors paulgv mentioned, this error is not there anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your dropdown toggles miss the data-toggle attributes which is required by Bootstrap : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">Jednotky<b class="caret"></b></a>
```

Comment: No, this didnt helped

Comment: Well I just checked on your website, looks like it's working now with data-toggle, did you change anything else to make it work ?